# Adding link post format to theme and permalink to rss feed

Tags: theme-development, post-formats

I have been in the process of adding the link post format to the thematic theme via a [child theme](https://github.com/MikeWills/MikeWillsThematic). To be honest, this is the first time I have done any sort of theme work with WordPress.

I have been able to change the title permalink to the link I am linking to and adding a symbol to the title so that there is a visual to someone to realize that there may be a different behavior. ([Example post](http://mikewills.me/blog/why-you-should-outsource-ops))

Should I be using thematic's filters to push out these changes to the theme or should I be using WordPress's? Also, how do I add a permalink in the RSS feed so people can still comment on my site (much like Daring Fireball)

I have been doing the following in `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Override the post title logic
 */
function mikewillsthematic_thematic_postheader_posttitle() {
    if (has_post_format('link')) {
        $posttitle = '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="';
        $posttitle .= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "post_format_data", true);
        $posttitle .= '" title="Direct link to article" rel="bookmark">';
        $posttitle .= '&#8734; ';
        $posttitle .= get_the_title();   
        $posttitle .= "</a></h2>\n";
    } else {
        // Handle other post types.
    }
    return $posttitle;
}
add_filter('thematic_postheader_posttitle', 'mikewillsthematic_thematic_postheader_posttitle');

/**
 * Override the RSS URL
 */
function mikewillsthematic_rss_permalink($permalink) {
    global $wp_query;
    if($url = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'post_format_data', true)) {
        return $url;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('the_permalink_rss', 'mikewillsthematic_rss_permalink');

/**
 * Override the RSS title
 */
function mikewillsthematic_rss_title($title) {

    if (has_post_format('link')) {
        $posttitle = '&#8734; ';
            $posttitle .= $title;
    } else 
        $posttitle = $title;

    return $posttitle;
}
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'mikewillsthematic_rss_title');
```

But I feel that this seems... excessive. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the right search terms and found out [how to add content to the RSS feed](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-content-and-completely-manipulate-your-wordpress-rss-feeds/).

```
// Add permalink to RSS feed
function mikewillsthematic_postrss($content) {
    if(is_feed() && has_post_format('link')) 
    {
        $content = $content.'<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'">Permalink</a></p>'; 
    }
    else {
        $content = $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'mikewillsthematic_postrss');
add_filter('the_content', 'mikewillsthematic_postrss');
```

Answer (score 1):

as a self-appointed thematic support guru, i can simplify your first filter:

```
/**
 * Override the post title logic for post format 'link'
 */
function mikewillsthematic_thematic_postheader_posttitle($posttitle) {
    if (has_post_format('link')) {
        $posttitle = '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="';
        $posttitle .= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "post_format_data", true);
        $posttitle .= '" title="Direct link to article" rel="bookmark">';
        $posttitle .= '&#8734; ';
        $posttitle .= get_the_title();   
        $posttitle .= "</a></h2>\n";
    } 
    return $posttitle;
}
add_filter('thematic_postheader_posttitle', 'mikewillsthematic_thematic_postheader_posttitle');
```

you might also want to do a test for the presence of the meta URL before you put it into the link.  i don't think your solution looks excessive.  you want to change the post permalink in 3 places, so i'm not surprised that you need 3 filters.  kind of wonder why that isn't default behavior for link formats, but i'm not versed enough in post formats to know why WP did it that way.

afaik you cannot filter the post title via WP.  when you have a solution (or before) please post at the [thematic forums](http://themeshaper.com/forums):

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have fixed that code. I'll ask on the Thematic forums about the filters.